# Java Generics. I have a compilation error, but the code works correctly

Tags: java, generics

I have code that is similar to this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new GenericsTest<Integer>(5).getSquare());
    }
}

class GenericsTest<T extends Integer> {
    private int square;

    public GenericsTest(T t) {
        square = t * t;
    }

    public int getSquare() {
        return square;
    }
}
```

*IntelliJ IDEA' Editor* underlines `t * t` like an error and says:

> Operator '*' cannot applied to 'T', 'T'

But it runs and it works correctly.

So, why is an *Editor* warning me about compilation error and how to fix it without editing the code?

Note: I understand that `Integer` is `final` and this code does not make sense - this is just for testing purposes.

Comment: It can't possibly run correctly. Perhaps you are running an old version of the class, where you had `int` or `Integer` instead of `T`? Try adding a `System.out.println("something")` to the constructor to see if you get the print.

Comment: `Integer` is a final class. I don't get the point to declare `class GenericsTest<T extends Integer> {`

Comment: You can always add `t.intValue() * t.intValue()`

Comment: The code could run if you use groovy, which Intellij is happy to tell you to use it, but apart from that, I do also think it runs the last successfully built version. (on a side note, ? extends Integer is not really useful as Integer is a final class, but I hope this is just for testing purposes)

Comment: There is several isues here, as @davidxxx said `Integer` is `final`, and if you use another IDE (as netbeans) It compiles without any problems.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One *might* think that this is an error, as in:

T is declared as **reference** type, and the arithmetic operators + * / and so on are only defined for the **primitive** types. So, sure - there is no "*" for *Objects*.

Then it still works because T is actually Integer; and therefore the compiler can *unbox*, resulting in something like:

```
t.intValue() * t.intValue()
```

But then: eclipse doesn't give a compile error here; instead it *warns* about the fact that `T extends Integer` doesn't make any sense (because the class Integer is **final** and can't be extended!)

Same for **javac**: your code compiles fine - no errors, no warnings.

Conclusion: actually, your source code seems to be **correct**. The java compiler is smart enough to understand that only Integers can be coming in - and then `t * t` is possible!

So the *real* error is that you get an error message in IntelliJ here! Thus the only "solution" I see: writing up a bug request against JetBrains.

Comment: *"Can I disable an error without editing the code?"* If you think *hiding* a problem is a valid solution I hopefully never come across something you coded...

Comment: @Игорь You can turn off the IDE warnings, but since you're doing strange things like expecting to extend only Integer class instead of `Number`, for example, I'd recommend leaving them on

Comment: its just intellij who tells you that T cannot be implicitly cast to an int primitive so the operators are invalid, however, because "T extends Integer" literally means "Integer" because it is a final class, the type T is replaced by Integer which is able to be wrapped to the int primitive... thus no error

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you, I guess that I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @GhostCat *"as methinks this is not an error."* right, but ist a short way from "methinks" warnings to warnings of "checkstyle" and "PMD" which point to more serious things...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Sure. But the point is: even javac -Xlint gives me a warning. And dont get me wrong: I am always advocating a **zero tolerance** policy. No errors, no warnings, no nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Your ide error is not correct. 
After type erasure, your method should be :

```
public GenericsTest(Integer t) {
    square = t * t;
}
```

as the generic T is declared `<T extends Integer>`.

And an `Integer` can be unboxed to an `int`.

Comment: I assume you didn't notice my earlier answer ;-)

Comment: It doesn't simply the question as it also changes the problem. With`Number`, things are differents. You should have a compilation error as `Number` cannot be unboxed to a primitive.